# Display contents from ListView defined in regular Activity Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-listview

I wanted to create a search view like the one Google uses. For this I created the following XML layout, which basically is a search bar and a button in the upper section of the screen and a ListView at the bottom of it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutSearch"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FF394952">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
        <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/searchTextBar" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">
            <requestFocus></requestFocus>
        </EditText>
        <Button android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/searchButton" android:text="Buscar"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/searchResultList"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the code of the textViewResource that the ArrayAdapter demands on its constructor:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</TextView>
```

Now, this is the code of the activity. So far, I just want to display the view with the contents (that's why I'm using a static String array for now).

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity{

    static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
        "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria"};


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.searchview);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES);
        ListView lv = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.searchResultList);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

          lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
              // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
          });   
    }
}
```

However, when I run the activity I see the search bar but it doesn't display the ListView.

I've tried changing the extension of SearchActivity to ListActivity, but the program just crashes when I try to start it. I'm also aware of the existence of the [Search Interface](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/index.html), but I just want to see this particular method work.

Why it doesn't display the contents of the ListView? Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use ListActivity you should be aware that ListActivity already has a ListView instance. You need to call its setListAdapter method to set the adapter for its ListView instead of instantiating your own ListView and setting the adapter on it. You can call getListView to get a  handle on ListActvity's ListView and then set the click listener on that.

Comment: Michaelg: Thanks for your answer! I'm quite aware that the ListActivity already has a ListView instance. However, how could I redirect the Adapter to the ListView I created? Because if I just skip the setContentView and do what you say, it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extend `ListActivity` then you must have a ListView with id `@android:id/list`. Change the id of your ListView, that should fix the crash when extending `ListActivity`.

Comment: OK, I did it, and indeed it doesn't crash now when extending ListActivity. However, I still can't see the text the countries' list. Yet, if I comment the setContentView line at the beggining of the onCreate method, I can see the list just fine, so I guess it's part of the configuration of the xml file. How could it work? Thanks for the help anyways aromero! :D